# AndEngine -- Having problems with attaching a new Sprite Entity

Tags: android, andengine, live-wallpaper

I've been doing trial and error for hours now and I have not yet come up with a solution for something that seems simple....
I am using the

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
```

method to detect if a user has changed their screen orientation. 
Eventually, it gets sent to this method where the entitys are attached to the scene:

```
public void BuildScene(final Scene scene){

       // Destroys current scene.
            scene.detachChildren();

        this.SpriteDayPortrait = new Sprite(-200, 0, 2000, 500, this.mParallaxLayerDayPortrait);
        this.SpriteDayLandscape = new Sprite(0, 0, 750, 500, this.mParallaxLayerDayLandscape);

    if (prefs.getString("frontImage", "1").equals("3"))
            {
                //Day
                if (orientationValue.equals("PORTRAIT"))
                {
                    Log.d("Orientation", "Portrait");
                    scene.detachChild(SpriteDayLandscape);

                    scene.attachChild(SpriteDayPortrait);

                }
                else if (orientationValue.equals("LANDSCAPE"))
                {
                    Log.d("Orientation", "Landscape");
                    scene.detachChild(SpriteDayPortrait);

                    scene.attachChild(SpriteDayLandscape);

                }
            }

}
```

This method is called to when the wallpaper is first created, and also when a user changes screen orientation.

I have tested this on my phone and it successfully displays the log messages when I switch orientations, which means that it is doing it what I want it to do.

The Problem--

The sprite child does not detach when this method is called to. If I am in Portrait mode, and switch to Landscape, the portrait sprite remains and I would like it to disappear, and vice versa.

I would be extremely happy if anyone could answer this I've been having a headache over this for probably 20 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem might be logic: You reassign the SpriteDayPortrait and SpriteDayLanscape before calling the branch about detaching them or attaching them.

So each time the detach script is called it is referring to a *new* instance of the sprite, rather than the old instance that you want to detach.

try moving the assignment of the sprites into another function that is only called when the scene is created:

```
// Move this
this.SpriteDayPortrait = new Sprite(-200, 0, 2000, 500, this.mParallaxLayerDayPortrait);
        this.SpriteDayLandscape = new Sprite(0, 0, 750, 500, this.mParallaxLayerDayLandscape);
```

Comment: Wow this just goes to show how new I am at this. It turns out I was using 
`scene = new Scene()`  in pretty much every method I needed to use scene. I removed those and declared `private final Scene = new Scene()` at the very top and everything is working perfectly. I can not thank you enough. Without you telling me to look where "the scene is created" I would have never tried that. You just solved a problem I've been trying to fix for 20 hours straight

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that since changing orientation in AndEngine doesn't exist (You are not allowed to change engine orientation), you should't make your game be using orientation changes (That would be weird for the user).

Anyways, `onConfigurationChanged` is called from the UI thread, and you should not manipulate objects of AndEngine but in the UpdateThread. It might cause some problems (However, if it would, your game would crash) so change it.

I think it happens because you didn't clear your `ParallaxBackground`  before setting the new background (Perhaps the old background hides the new one?)
Keep a reference to your last `ParallaxEntity` then remove it from the background before adding a new one.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that this is a live wallpaper and I need it to be able to switch to a new image once the orientation is changed because the bitmap expands a large amount once it is switched to Landscape mode. I have updated my code. Would you mind reading over it please?

Comment: Maybe this is off topic, but do you know of a device that switches orientation of a wallpaper? I have 3 android devices and all of them have a single wallpaper orientation.

Comment: Devices that have pull out keyboards sometimes use Landscape mode. Also, if users use a different launcher such as "Launcher Pro" they can switch between Portrait and Landscape by rotating their phone